# Sentinel Watchlist Creation Error - Could Not Be Saved Properly

Tags: azure-sentinel

Attempting to create a watchlist on Sentinel but am met with the following error:
[image: Error message]

This is an error that has only occurred after moving to Windows 11, that may not be related to the issue. The CSV data is listed below and does not contain blanks, it does contain caps and lower within a column.
What special characters are allowed? if that's the issue?

| User | Manager | Date | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| email | email | 20210802 | Can include () ? |
| EMAIL | EMAIL | not in system | Can include () ? |

The CSV itself is valid

[image: screenshot]

I have tried:
removing each column and uploading
renaming the watchlist
ensuring no blanks